# Disable Magento Gift Card Extension

Tags: magento2, module, gift-card, enable-disable

I want to disable (complecty remove everything that comes with this module, I mean options in My account, checkout, cart etc) but disabling it by command seems problematic beacuse of modules that depends on it, do you have any idea how can I remove this feature from magento?